# Mac Automator to "Get Info" on sing in iTunes and then press next until the last song

Tags: macos, itunes, id3, automator

Without getting into details, I am updating ID3 tags outside of iTunes and would like to import all of that data into iTunes. Before iTunes 10 I was able to select all songs and click "Get Info" - this would automatically pull all the updated ID3 tags for every song. It seems like the only way to do that now is to either play each song individually OR "Get Info" and continue pressing "Next" for every single song. I want to setup an action in Automator to do this for me. I have never used it before and am having some trouble with it. I would appreciate if somebody could give me a hand setting this up. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found exactly what I needed here: http://marv.kordix.com/archives/000860.html It's an Applescript called "Refresh Selected Tags". You select whatever songs you want and click "Refresh Selected Tags" - simple as that!

Answer (score 1):

how about trying this with a few songs first:
select the songs, right click and select 'convert id3 tags'. select the most recent version.
not sure if that will work.

otherwise make a new automator workflow, press the record button at the top, switch to itunes press command+i (get info) then command+n (next button), then stop the workflow recording.

you'll see automator made a new action called 'watch me do'. test it out. if this works, try holding option and dragging the command+n part of the action underneath it to duplicate it. you can then select both and duplicate those, then duplicate the 4 you have and so on. you should have a long list of command+n. then, in itunes select the song you want to start from and then press play in automator.